# How to handle nested scroll container with mousewheel control (Swiper.js)

Tags: javascript, scroll, slider, swiper.js

I have a website that uses Swiper.js for its main layout. Every section is a slide. Some of these slides need to be scrollable. I created nested swiper instances for each of them and enabled `cssmode` and `freemode` according to the developer's suggestion.

Naturally, mousewheel control only works for one swiper at a time so I need to disable the mousewheel control of the main swiper while scrolling a nested swiper and enable it again when done.

I achieved this by using event listeners for `slideChangeTransitionEnd` on the main swiper to disable the mousewheel when a scrollable slide is active. When the top or bottom of a nested swiper is reached the `toEdge` event fires and enables the main swiper again.

So far so good, the only problem I now have is when you scroll the main swiper to a nested swiper and instead of scrolling down you scroll up again the `toEdge` event does not fire and the user needs to scroll down a little to be able to scroll up again.

I created a reproduction of my issue here: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-scroller-hh7j6c?file=/index.html)

Sometimes the nested swiper overshoots a little which makes reproducing the problem impossible. To reproduce:

- Open the demo
- Click the second slide in the pagination (on the right)
- Try to scroll up again (impossible)
- Scroll down a little
- Scroll up again, the event fires, and scrolling the main swiper works again

I also tried to manually set the position a tiny bit when reaching a nested slider so the `toEdge` event fires every time, but this resulted in layout shifts.

I have been troubleshooting this problem for at least a week now and would be very happy to find a solution for this.